# Explaining this printf with CR and LF

Tags: zsh, newline

Follow the examples:

`printf "abcde\r1"`

> 1%

`printf "abcde\r1\n"`

> 1bcde

I couldn't understand this behavior... I was thinking about these answers:

> 1bcde%

and

> 1bcde

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Comment: Actually, I was studying about control characters, and start to make some testing at terminal (ZSH no Ubuntu)

Comment: I guess that your terminal erases the line before it outputs something new to it. If you do a `printf "abcde\r"`, you don't see any output at all. I think you would need something like _ncurses_  to overwrite part of the terminal area. Another possibility would be to use [`tput`](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Moving_the_cursor_with_tput) for doing funny things with the cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character `%` in your output is not part of the output of your printf command. This is only an indication from the shell that the last output line was not finished by a newline character. Such a '%' is added at the current position on the line and every characters that follow this current position are erased.

Here is a proof that the character `%` is not part of the output of printf:

```
fenyo% printf "ab"
ab%
fenyo% printf "ab" | od -xa
0000000    6261
          a   b
0000002
fenyo%
```

As you can see, the output is only made of 2 bytes corresponding to characters "a" and "b".

Therefore, we can explain the two behaviours:

1. About the behaviour of `printf "abcde\r1\n"`, here is the explanation:

- the last argument to printf is a newline (`\n`), so the shell will not add a `%`;
- there is a `\r` just before `1`, therefore the 1 will be printed at the start of line, erasing the character `a` that has been printed previously at the same position.

  Those two facts explain why you get the output `1bcde`

2. About the behaviour of `printf "abcde\r1"`, here is the explanation:

- there is a `\r` just before `1`, therefore the 1 will be printed at the start of line, erasing the character `a` that has been printed previously at the same position. At this step, the output is `1bcde` and the current writing position is on the `b`;
- the last argument to printf is not a newline (`\n`), so the shell will add a `%` and remove everything else after that on the same line. Since the current position is on the `b`, this character is replaced by `%` and the remaining characters (`cdef`) are erased.

  Those two facts explain why you get the output `1%`

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning that you can configure the character which is displayed, if the output does not terminate in a newline: You have to set the variable `PROMPT_EOL_MARK`. For instance, I set this variable in my .zshrc to a rarely used unicode character. This allows me to see better when I `cat` a file, whether the file is missing a newline at the end.